# Linux-mint new SSD not recognized

Tags: linux, linux-mint, ssd

I have two external SSD's, an old SSD that is getting recognized, and a new one I just bought that is not. The new SSD is working when I plug it in, but it doesn't show up. I have used the terminal command `lsblk` and it shows up in the terminal (sda 223,6 GB). What can I do to make linux mint recognize it?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a new SSD it probably doesn't have any filesystem on it so you need to format it first. Use either GNOME Disks or GParted to partition it and create a filesystem on it.

With GNOME Disks select the disk and from the main menu select *Format disk* to create the [partition table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning) on it and then use the plus button to add a partition and format it.

[image]
[image]

After this you should see the disk (actually the partition you just created) in the file browser.

Comment: Thank you so much